# Do good-aligned gods place curses on creatures when angered to a significant degree?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, religions-and-deities, golarion

In literature, many deities are seen to curse those that anger them.

In Pathfinder (Golarion) lore, are there instances of good-aligned god(s) enacting nasty curses (perhaps so nasty that it could be construed as evil) if angered enough?

Comment: I edited your question fairly heavily, but I believe I kept the spirit of the question in there. If you don't agree, feel free to rollback or re-edit the question. I noticed an unnecessary amount of setup regarding the abilities of Deities that didn't really pertain to "is this in the lore" so I wanted to make it more concise (and clarify that you are in fact talking about Golarion because that "is" Pathfinder)

Comment: @Ifusaso so all pathfinder lore is Golarion? Because I meant pathfinder in general not just one type/setting

Comment: As KRyan's answer points out... pretty much yes. They didn't make it "official" in 1e (when Paizo adopted a bunch of rules from the 3.5 SRD and was avoiding Copyright infringement like the plague) but the content they wrote for it is in Paizo's setting Golarion. You could use Pathfinder rules for other settings "officially" but then that's because there wasn't an "official" setting. You're not asking about mechanics (which is all P1e really is if you get down to it). I don't know of any other setting that Paizo made for Pathfinder

Comment: @Ifusaso okay thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Golarion, which is kinda-sorta the default setting of Pathfinder 1e (and explicitly the default setting of 2e), the answer is “Yes.” Unfortunately this one we have from canon. I warn you, it’s ***terrible***. Also, I warn you that the following contains spoilers from *Wrath of the Righteous*, but since that adventure is awful, I don’t know how much you should care.

> Towards the end of the adventure, the adventurers are swept into the divine realm of the lawful good goddess Iomedae, who supposedly embodies honor and justice. She poses three questions to them. These are all trick questions, where she judges not their answers but *how* they answer, and if they *answer in any manner other than the exact ones she was looking for,* an unseen choir of angels blasts the party for massive sonic damage, no save. If they fail to be sufficiently respectful towards her despite this treatment, they are subject to permanent deafness, no save, and permanent muteness at DC 40 Fortitude save. None of these conditions can be cured by anything save divine intervention. If the PCs protest this treatment or try to defend their position, this escalates as far as permanently blinding them, changing their alignment to chaotic (or chaotic evil if they attempt to physically or magically defend themselves), loss of any divine spellcasting for anyone who worships her, and throwing them to some random corner of the material plane. In other words, that character may very well be just out of the game, period, and a new character must be rerolled. At ***15th-level*** after likely ***real-life years*** of play to reach this point.

In other words, James Jacobs is not a great writer or world-builder, and this particular example of his writing and world-building is a travesty. You shouldn’t play *Wrath of the Righteous*, and you should take this precedent with a large grain of salt.

> Seriously, to put the problem here in starker terms, Iomedae literally kidnaps the PCs, shines a bright light in their face, and starts interrogating them—and if she doesn’t like their answers or other behavior, she subjects them to pain and mutilation. We have a word for that: **torture.**

That said, good-aligned gods cursing people doesn’t have to be this poorly-justified; better writing can achieve scenarios where a curse may well seem good and justified. After all, the good gods are not all gods of mercy and forgiveness, and a curse may very well be a way of dispensing justice and/or protecting others from the predations of the one who has been cursed. [*Mark of justice*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mark-of-justice/) is a “necromancer [curse]” spell that appears on the judgment subdomain of the law domain—a domain likely held by most lawful good deities, and most of them probably live up to that title better than Iomedae. If they can dispense the spell to their followers, one would expect that they can certainly use it themselves.

Comment: That. Is. Brutal. Definitely avoiding that that adventure like the plague.

Comment: Now I need to read the AP to see how that's actually written. That sounds more like a capricious GM to me, but I don't know how specific the section in question is.

Comment: @Ifusaso I was reading from *Wrath of the Righteous*. The questions, desired style of answering, punishments for answering incorrectly, for “mocking” Iomedae, or for attacking her are spelled out. There’s some wiggle room on what constitutes “mocking” but the text makes clear that Iomedae expects humble awe and respect, and nothing else. The text also sort of implies that this is all very obvious and it seems to suggest that to act otherwise is “asking for it.” James Jacobs’ defense of this section has not been that this kind of description is inaccurate, that I have seen.

Comment: Looking into it a little, [he does feel like he went too far on the punishment](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qngl?Book-5-Discussion-on-Iomedae-SPOILERS-AHOY#6)

Comment: His next post is "don't treat this as canon"

Comment: And further on he also points out that she retcons her own shenanigans

Comment: @Ifusaso I’m glad the tons and tons of criticism finally got through to him, but frankly until I see an errata to *Wrath of the Righteous*, I’m sorry, but it **is** canon, and his forum post isn’t. He can put his money where his mouth is, and issue an errata coupled with an apology to everyone who wasted money on this, or he can just accept that this is part of his legacy. Besides, “toned down” the punishment? He had a nominally-LG goddess kidnap the PCs and torture them! ***Any*** punishment is absolutely preposterous.

Comment: You're also describing it in the most extreme context. From another point of view, a busy deity proving that her power *is* in fact greater than the Champions' can be seen as reasonable if they're being uppity instead of listening to her. She is, in the strictest sense, calling you before her to capital-J Judge your worth. She wants to know that she can entrust the future of the (world, I think?) to you. Also I feel like torture implies some amount of being drawn out. And I don't expect to come back from *any* deistic encounter unscathed unless I'm a a card-carrying devout member.

Comment: @Ifusaso You seem to feel the need to defend Paizo from my criticism at every turn and that’s fine, but not here. It’s torture. Iomedae would, utterly without question, be convicted in the Hague for a crime against humanity here. And she is supposed to be good and honor and justice incarnate—she should, if anything, be _more_ advanced than our modern sensibilities. It’s also atrocious game design, “rewarding” players with an awful, feelbad moment that literally risks destroying their characters and all of the player’s investment in them. There is no defense here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99257/discussion-between-ifusaso-and-kryan).